# Qt Post request executing but failing

Tags: c++, qt, post, network-programming, qt5

Somehow I'm having trouble with Qt. I'm trying to send a POST request to a server.

Before I made a C++ program with Windows headers to execute the POST request which worked fine, but now I want to make a GUI for the program.

I'm 100% sure the php code on the server side is fine, and I followed examples on Qt and Stack Overflow, but I'm not receiving any data in my database with Qt.

Here is the POST code:

HttpPOST.h

```cpp
#ifndef HTTPPOST_H
#define HTTPPOST_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QHttpMultiPart>

class HttpPOST : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    HttpPOST(QString url);
    void postData(QList<QString> parameter, QList<QString> value);
    const QString EQUALS = "=";
    const QString AND = "&";
signals:

public slots:
    void onFinish(QNetworkReply *reply);
private:
    QNetworkAccessManager * manager;
    QUrl url;
    QByteArray data;
};

#endif // HTTPPOST_H
```

HttpPOST.cpp

```cpp
#include "httppost.h"

HttpPOST::HttpPOST(QString url)
{
    this->url = QUrl(url);
}

void HttpPOST::postData(QList<QString> parameter, QList<QString> value)
{
    data.clear();
    for (int i=0; i<parameter.size(); i++) {
        data.append(parameter[i]);
        data.append(EQUALS);
        data.append(value[i]);
        if(i < parameter.size()-1){data.append(AND); }
    }
    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(manager,
            SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
            this,
            SLOT(onFinish(QNetworkReply*)));
    connect(manager,
            SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
            manager,
            SLOT(deleteLater()));
    QHttpMultiPart *http = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType, this);

    QHttpPart receiptPart;
    receiptPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, 
                          QVariant("form-data; name=\"data\""));
    receiptPart.setBody(data);

    http->append(receiptPart);

    manager->post(QNetworkRequest(url), http);
}

void HttpPOST::onFinish(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    qDebug("POST request finished!");
    qDebug(reply->readAll());
}
```

I'm currently clueless on what I'm doing wrong.

Anyone that can help my it's for a project at work.

Comment: Where does the issue occur? You say it "fails" but that's not very clear. Does `onFinish` ever get called? Does the server not get any incoming request? Stupid question but, is the url correct?

Comment: @mrg95 The on Finish never gets called. The data of the request is in this format:```param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3``` and the url is correct. The server is not getting any request, its failing somewhere in my program.

Comment: @mgr95 to give you a example of how I use my class:
```c++
    
    HttpPOST database("localhost/mw2018/Database/POST.php");
    QList<QString> parameter;
    QList<QString> value;

    parameter.append("table");
    parameter.append("Value");
    value.append("TEST");
    value.append("testvalue");


   database.postData(parameter, value);```

Answer (score 0):

If you just went from Windows C++ to Qt C++. Do you have a QApplication, and do you called exec() in the main function?

The Qt IO classes won't work without an eventloop. It sounds like you either don't have the main event loop, or are in a different thread without one.